# Why AsyncSocket can't connect to host when using dispatch_async() method?

Tags: ios, sockets, asyncsocket, dispatch-async

I'm a little confused when using dispatch_async method to use AsyncSocket.
Here's my code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    _socket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    [_socket connectToHost:@"192.168.1.122" onPort:9501 error:nil];
    [self sendCurrentLocation];
});
```

I use this code to connect, but It didn't work, event `- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock willDisconnectWithError:(NSError *)err` isn't invoked.
Anybody knows why? thanks.

p.s. forgive my English.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncSocket data transmission is asynchronous, it is placed  data in the queue, use threads to send, so we do not need to do it again asynchronously.